# Python connect to Hive use pyhs2 and Kerberos authentication

Tags: python, jdbc, hive

I'm connecting Hive use pyhs2. But the Hive server required Kerberos authentication. Anyone knows how to convert the JDBC string to pyhs2 parameter? Like:
`jdbc:hive2://biclient2.server.163.org:10000/default;principal=hive/app-20.photo.163.org@HADOOP.HZ.NETEASE.COM?mapred.job.queue.name=default`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it will be something like this:

```
pyhs2.connect(host='biclient2.server.163.org',
                   port=10000,
                   authMechanism="KERBEROS",
                   password="something",
                   user='your_user@HADOOP.HZ.NETEASE.COM')
```

I'm also doing the same, I still not succeed, but at least having a meaningful errorcode: 
(Server hive/xxx@yyy.COM not found in Kerberos database)

Comment: I'm succeed use what you said, and add a `configuration` parameter like: `conn_config = {'krb_host': 'app-20.photo.163.org', 'krb_service': 'hive'}`

Comment: From standpoint of security, in Kerberos authentication username/password should be taken from an active Kerberos ticket or from a keytab. See @pele88 answer below which goes with the former option.

Comment: plus one, but pyhs2 is no longer maintained http://stackoverflow.com/a/38666630/470583

Answer (score 2):

This connection string will work as long as the user running the script has a valid kerberos ticket:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='biclient2.server.163.org',
                    port=10000,
                    authMechanism="KERBEROS") as conn:

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
            print cur.getDatabases()
```

Username, password and any other configuration parameters are not 
 passed through the KDC.

Comment: plus one, but pyhs2 is no longer maintained http://stackoverflow.com/a/38666630/470583

Comment: @Ruslan Yes I'm aware but couldn't get any alternatives working with a kerberised cluster - I've tried both Impyla and PyHive. Have you?