# Problems installing pyhs2 in python3

Tags: hive, pip

I am using CentOS 6.5 and want to access a remote hive server. But I am unable to install pyhs2 using `pip install pyhs2`.

I have installed all the required dependencies:

- gcc-c++
- python-devel.x86_64
- cyrus-sasl-devel.x86_64

But still I get the same error:

```
Failed building wheel for sasl
Failed to build sasl
Installing collected packages: sasl, pyhs2
Running setup.py install for sasl
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vq9qfls4/sasl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bjam3ra0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing sasl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building '_saslwrapper' extension
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isasl -I/opt/include/python3.4m -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sasl/saslwrapper.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
sasl/saslwrapper.cpp: In member function ‘void saslwrapper::ClientImpl::interact(sasl_interact_t*)’:
sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:341: warning: unused variable ‘input’
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isasl -I/opt/include/python3.4m -c sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘void SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg(const char*)’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:884: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PySwigClientData* PySwigClientData_New(PyObject*)’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1275: error: ‘PyClass_Check’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* PySwigObject_format(const char*, PySwigObject*)’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1348: error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1350: error: ‘PyString_Format’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* PySwigObject_repr(PySwigObject*)’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1380: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1380: error: ‘PyString_FromFormat’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1388: error: ‘PyString_ConcatAndDel’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘int PySwigObject_print(PySwigObject*, FILE*, int)’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1402: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* PySwigObject_str(PySwigObject*)’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1415: error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyTypeObject* _PySwigObject_type()’:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: ‘coercion’ was not declared in this scope
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: too many initializers for ‘PyNumberMethods’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: invalid conversion from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*)’ to ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: invalid conversion from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ to ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*)’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: invalid conversion from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*)’ to ‘int (*)(PyObject*)’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(PyObject*)’ to ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*)’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1624: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before numeric constant
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1604: warning: unused variable ‘swigobject_doc’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1606: warning: unused variable ‘PySwigObject_as_number’
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1637: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx: At global scope:
sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:1641: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/stdexcept:38,
                 from sasl/saslwrapper_wrap.cxx:2542:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected declaration before end of line
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vq9qfls4/sasl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bjam3ra0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vq9qfls4/sasl
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve formatting - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with Python3 and the dependency SASL. SASL is currently coded for Python2. This is seen with the error 'PyString_AsString not being declared in the scope'.

A short term solution, if possible, would be to use Python2. Long term, either the SASL dependency will need to be updated for Python3 or pyhs2 will need to use a different dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update:
It seems that now the "installation" of this module with pip-Python3 (I tried with 3.5 and 3.6) is possible.

However, even if it installs you won't be able to use it in Python3 because the module has never been ported to such version (for instance, it still uses  the "cStringIO" module, which no longer exists in Python3).

Since pyhs2 is no longer maintained (see note in https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2), you're stuck with Python2 or you'd better switch to another tool to connect to HiverServer2.

Comment: Is this still the case, or is there any update on this 3 years on?