# Required field 'sessionHandle' is unset! while using hive with python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have tried various approach of using hive with python.

One is

[How to Access Hive via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370431/how-to-access-hive-via-python)

Also tried https://sites.google.com/site/tingyusz/home/blogs/hiveinpython

Where I am getting

```
  File "py_hive.py", line 8, in <module>
    database='default') as conn:
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/connections.py", line 52, in __init__
    cur.execute(query) 
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/cursor.py", line 61, in execute
    res = self.client.ExecuteStatement(query)
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 244, in ExecuteStatement
    return self.recv_ExecuteStatement()
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 260, in recv_ExecuteStatement
    raise x
thrift.Thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'sessionHandle' is unset! Struct:TExecuteStatementReq(sessionHandle:null, statement:USE default, confOverlay:{})
```

Python code:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='dmeet-master02.inetuhosted.net',
                   port=10000,
                   authMechanism="PLAIN",
                   user='userk',
                   password='userk',
                   database='default') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #Show databases
        print cur.getDatabases()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute("select * from table")

        #Return column info from query
        print cur.getSchema()

        #Fetch table results
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
            break
```

any hint on this?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a similar initialization code for connecting with Hive and it works for me.

But, I can see that it's failing to initialize the connection.
The field *sessionHandle* is set internally while opening connection with the server. It is **unset** (or set to None) when corresponding socket connection can't be opened. Try reaching without specifying a database and see if it works.

Comment: Can you please make it more simple?