# Java Hive connectivity

Tags: java, hive, connectivity

I am trying to connect Hive database with my Java code. I have googled a lot and found about Hive_Client, but there were so many errors, and dependency, can someone help me out with the code and the library files required for them.

Comment: My advice > see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005061/where-is-apache-hive-jdbc-driver-for-download/36005379#36005379 > and Kerberos authentication adds a good deal of pain, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362326/connect-to-kerberised-hive-using-jdbc-from-remote-windows-system/39365297#39365297

Comment: Thanks for that help, Since I am new to this, can you please elaborate, which libraries they meant by "the SLF4J family and friends" in the first link

Comment: The way Hadoop does its logging, it's `slf4j-api.jar` + `slf4j-log4j12.jar` + `log4j.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Hive provides a [JDBC driver](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC) which can i.e. be found in the [Maven Repo](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc). Examples on how to connect via JDBC are [provided in the Hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBCClientSampleCode).

Comment: Yes sir/ma'am, I completely agree with you, but with that jar files, I need some more jar files. By this question, I want to know them.

Comment: What about using a build tool like gradle or maven, which takes care of all needed dependencies? If that's not an option, they are listed in the aforementioned Maven repository.

Comment: No sir/ma'am , I am talking about with hive_client**.jar, the other libraries like hadoop-auth**.jar, hadoop-common**.jar

Comment: And I'm suggesting using the JDBC driver as an alternative.

Comment: My 2 cents: that Hive JDBC driver is a joke. Even the "standalone" JAR has dependencies to the Hadoop client, and in case you use kerberos auth, you also need the *native* libs (too bad there is no official build for Windows...) Plus the lack of backward compatibility on client side. Plus the fact that it's not JDBC4-compliant. Plus the fact that is not wholly JDBC-compliant, some tools will refuse to use it because it implements so little of the API.