# How to access Hive created in EMR cluster from Python

Tags: python, hive, amazon-emr, pyhive

My hive table resides in EMR cluster.
I have created SSH tunnel :

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 -i atlas-emr-xx.pem hadoop@ec2-aa-bbb-ccc-ddd.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I am able to create and access the hive tables thru HUE from http://localhost:8888/

Now, I need to access the hive tables from Python and the code executes from my on premise machine.

My code :

```
from pyhive import hive
import pandas as pd
conn = hive.Connection(host='localhost', port=8888, username='admin',auth='NOSASL')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM atlas_emr.us_disease limit 10", conn)
print(df.head())
```

Error i get :

```
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Hive\venv\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TSocket.py", line 143, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

And if I modify the code :

```
conn = hive.Connection(host='localhost', port=8888, username='admin')
```

The error I get is :

```
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'
```

I have followed all the codes mentioned in [How to Access Hive via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370431/how-to-access-hive-via-python). But no luck

Let me know if it is possible to access Hive created in EMR cluster. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-to-data-source-hive.html to connect to hive from EMR

Comment: To be precise, I am copying snowflake tables' structure and creating those tables in Hive. But Athena does not support create tables.